# Child Theme's Read More Text

Tags: php, functions, child-theme, read-more

I'm sitting here trying to figure out how to change the Read More text. I'm currently creating a Child Theme of [Oxygen](http://alienwp.com/themes/oxygen/) and as far as I can tell, they don't have a function to easily change it.

I want to change the text without copying over the entire `index.php` file though this is line 70:

```
<a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Read Article', 'oxygen' ); ?> &rarr;</a>
```

I've tried different methods of changing it and even created a question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907826/wordpress-child-themes-altering-php-files) but have had no luck.

Is it possible, with this theme, to change the Read More text without copying over the entire `index.php` file and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this line of code is hardcoded in the *index.php* file rather than called via a function you only really have two options:

- Write your own function to call this code (with your chosen read more text), then replace the relevant section in the child theme's *index.php* file with a call to this function. The function would go in your child theme's functions.php file.
- Create a copy of the *index.php* file in your child theme, then change the hardcoded read more text to what you want it to be.

Obviously neither of these solutions solve the original problem (not wanting to copy over the *index.php* file).

It's also worth taking note of the comment at the top of the index.php file:

> This is the default template.  It is used when a more specific template can't be found to display posts. It is unlikely that this template will ever be used, but there may be rare cases.

Therefore for this change to take effect on all relevant pages you'll also want to edit *page-template-front.php*, *archives.php*, *page-template-archives.php* and *search.php* (I think that's all of them).

A more hacky approach would be to write a 'find and replace'-style function that looks for the current read more text and replaces it with something else, then call this function from your child theme's footer.php file.

In short, I don't think there's a way to switch out this text without copying *at least* one include or page template into your child theme.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Modify_The_Read_More_Link_Text):

```
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
function modify_read_more_link() {
    return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Your Read More Link Text</a>';
}
```

Add this to the child theme's functions.php.

Comment: As you may not have seen in the SO page, that was the suggested answer there and it didn't work.

Comment: Oops, missed that. Re-reading the question again I see no other possibility that copying the files from the parent theme and making the changes. You could contact the developer of the parent theme and ask for a hook function to be used so that can be replaced in a child theme.